# After update hibernate org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to find column with logical name:

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, foreign-keys, composite-primary-key

I was using Hibernate 4.2 and app was works fine.

After update to 4.3 I'm getting the hibernate error org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to find column with logical name: cd_banco in TB_AGENCIA.

```
@Table(name = "TB_AGENCIA")
public class Agencia {

    private Banco   banco;
    private String  codigoAgencia;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "cd_banco", referencedColumnName = "cd_banco")
    public Banco getBanco(){
        return banco;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "cd_agencia")
    public String getCodigoAgencia(){
        return codigoAgencia;
    }
}
```

The database structure is:

```
|-------------------|
|    TB_AGENCIA     |
|-------------------|
| cd_banco PK, FK   |
| cd_agencia PK     |
| ...               |
|-------------------|

|-------------------|
|      TB_BANCO     |
|-------------------|
| cd_banco PK       |
| ...               |
|-------------------|
```

I added a bidirectional relationship in the Banco class, but didn't work

```
public class Banco{

    private String codigo;
    private List<Agencia> agencias;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "cd_banco")
    public String getCodigo(){
        return codigo;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="banco")
    public List<Agencia> getAgencias() {
        return agencias;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the banco class definition?

Comment: Remove referencedColumnName = "cd_banco" from the join column annotation.

Comment: I did this, but didn't work. I upgraded to 5.0.12 and it worked but I'd like to know what happened.